# Web3 Could not find name 'Web3'. Did you mean 'web3'

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps

My code works but I am getting this with Web3 dotted.

> Could not find name 'Web3'. Did you mean 'web3'?

`const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || infuraUrl);`

When I try to fix it by doing this:
`const web3 = new web3(web3.givenProvider || infuraUrl);`
I wont get the error but I will get this in Browser console:

> app.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'web3' before initialization

My code works with Web3 being in capital, is there any reason to change it. If so why?

Comment: Hi trox! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! How are you importing web3 into your code? Are you following their documentation? In particular the "Getting started" section here https://docs.web3js.org/.

Answer (score 1):

dev Advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here!

It looks like that might be an issue with how you are importing the web3.js package.

This is how you import the package and create a `web3` instance:

```js
const { Web3 } = require("web3");

const node_url = "CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(node_url);
```

Now you can use the `web3` instance to call RPC methods like this:

```js
const { Web3 } = require("web3");
const NODE_URL = "CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

async function getLatestBlockNumber() {
  const block = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber();
  console.log(`Latest block: ${block}`);
}
  
getLatestBlockNumber()
```

> Those examples are based on web3.js V 4.x

You can find more examples on the [Chainstack docs](https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-blocks-rpc-methods) (full disclosure, I made those) or in the official [web3.js](https://docs.web3js.org/) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you imported your web3

> Const {Web3} = require (‘web3’)